# Calling a component method via click event on a button in the same component but its not defining on the instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

why is `greet` returning `[Vue warn]: Property or method "greet" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in <Inputs>)` when i press the corresponding button?

```
 <template id="input-template">
           ...
   <div v-for="(inputs, inputName) in renderedSystemComponent">
      <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>
  ...
 </template>    


Vue.component('inputs', {
    template: '#input-template',

    props: ['systemComponents','selectedSystemProductComponents'],

    data () {
        return {
            renderedSystemComponent: [],

        }
    },
    methods: {
        greet: function () {
            alert('Hello ');
        }
    },
    watch: {
        selectedSystemProductComponents: function() {
          ...
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a problem in the code you are showing, assuming `input-template` has one root. http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/dvEQzd?editors=1010

Comment: It does thanks, got it figured. npm run watch wasn't working correctly.